# mat-select: select current value when input key is Number

Tags: arrays, angular, numbers

I've a variable `tipo` of type Number. When I do this:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Tipo" formControlName="tipo">
  <mat-option [value]="item.key" *ngFor="let item of arrayOfValues | keyvalue">
    {{ item.value }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

it doesn't select the current `tipo` for the dropdown (because its Number, not string).
`.key` seems to works/match only for string (if in fact I change `typo` to string, it works).

What's the correct way to match keys as integer in this case?

Tried this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  tipo: [data.tipo.toString(), [Validators.required]]
});
```

which seems to works, but I don't like so much it as workaround (it basically treats Number as string, only for match the purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not with the `tipo` formControl type. The cause is the type of the `item.key` which is probably a string.
Perhaps if the `item.key` and the `tipo` are both numbers, the desired behavior will work fine.

The `KeyValue` will provide a key of string type, so add `+` to convert it to number : `<mat-option [value]="+item.key" ...>`

[KeyValue Pipe documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

[Working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dyrzgz)

Comment: Thats for sure. Thats why I place .tostring and it works. The question is: how make it work keeping int? :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can keep it number by converting the item.key to number by just adding '+' operator

Comment: more elegant solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the incompatibility of the value type without casting it, you should override the compareWith method like this:

```
@ViewChild(MatSelect, {static:true}) select!:MatSelect;

ngOnInit(){
  this.select.compareWith = (o1,o2)=>o1==o2
}
```

This will override the [original](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/select/select.ts#L347) compareWith that use ===.